# Update current class property when any item in observable collection changes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class

```
public class SomeModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

  public ObservableCollection<SomeSubModel> SubModels {get; set;}

  public int Sum { get { return SubModels.Sum(x=> x.Count) }}

  private string _url;
  public string Url
  {
    get { return _url; }
    set
    {
        _url = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

}

public class SomeSubModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

  private string _count;
  public string Count
  {
    get { return _count; }
    set
    {
        _count = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

}
```

I'm going to use binding to `SomeSubModel.Sum` in WPF UI.

The `SomeSubModel.Count` property is changed very frequently.

How to notify that `SomeSubModel.Sum` is changed when property `SomeSubModel.Count` from any item in `SomeModel.SubModels` observable collection is changed to reflect the actual `SomeSubModel.Sum` in WPF UI through the binding?

The main goal is to reflect in UI the actual Sum of all Count's of objects in observable collection.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fire a notify property changed for the Sum property as well in that case:

```
private string _count;
public string Count
{
    get { return _count; }
    set
    {
        _count = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) 
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Sum"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it work if "Count" and "Sum" are properties of different classes?

Comment: No, you'd have to call a method on the other class then, telling it to raise `PropertyChanged`. In that case I'd reconsider the design, although it's hard to tell how without seeing your actual use case.

Comment: I write a simple segmented download manager. Each file download actually is done by several segments in parallel. There is a FileDownload class (SomeModel  from example) and FileSegment class (SomeSubModel from example). FileDownload contains collection of FileSegments. The actual downloading is reflected in FileSegment model but to summarize everything and display to user in GUI the FileDownload model is used. This is the real use case.

Comment: Then you'd need the `FileSegments` class to call a method on the `FileDownload` class, which in turn raises the `PropertyChanged` for `Sum`